# Copying two source files to one destination in python

Tags: python, shutil

You guys were super helpful for my last question so I figured I'd see if you can help me out again.  Right now, I have a bunch of folders named P2_## with each of them containing two folders 0_output and 1_output.  Inside the each of the output folders I have a file named Bright_Combo.txt.  What I want to do is copy the data from both output folders into a Bright_Sum.txt file in the P2_## folder.  This is the code I've got so far, but the problem is that it only copies data from the 1_output folder and in one case save an empty copy of the Bright_Sum file into a 0_output folder.

```
import os
import re
import shutil


def test():
    file_paths = []
    filenames = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Users/Bashe/Desktop/121210 p2"):
        for file in files:
            if re.match("Bright_Combo.txt",file):
                file_paths.append(root)
                filenames.append(file)
    return file_paths, filenames

def test2(file_paths, filenames):
    for file_path, filename in zip(file_paths, filenames):
        moving(file_path, filename)

def moving(root,file):
    bcombo = open(os.path.join(root,os.pardir, "Bright_Sum.txt"),'w')
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(root,"Bright_Combo.txt"), os.path.join(root, os.pardir,   "Bright_sum.txt"))

file_paths, filenames = test()
test2(file_paths, filenames)
```

Thanks for the help everyone =)

Comment: Please indent correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i cannot give you complete solution, but i can give you an idea...
This is what i implented for your usecase:

**code:**

```
import os,re,shutil
f=[]
file='Bright_Combo.txt'
for root,dirs,files in os.walk('/home/ghantasa/test'):
    if file in files:
        f.append(os.path.join(root,file))

for fil in f:
    with open(fil,'r') as readfile:
        data = readfile.readlines()
    with open(os.path.join('/'.join(fil.split('/')[:-2]),'Bright_Sum.txt'),'a') as      writefile:
    writefile.write(''.join(data))
```

That worked for me and i hope you can tweak it according to your need.

Hope this helps .. :)

Comment: Can you please vote if it helps in anyway ?. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to append the second file to the first file, you can just use `bash` directly. My code below assumes the `P2_##` folders are located at your `root` directory.

```bash
root="/Users/Bashe/Desktop/121210 p2/"
for folder in $(ls -1 "$root/P2_*"); do
    cp "$folder/0_output/Bright Combo.txt" "$folder/Bright Sum.txt"
    cat "$folder/1_output/Bright Combo.txt" >> "$folder/Bright Sum.txt"
done
```